# XSD for two complex types

Tags: file, xsd, bpel

I am using File adapter (SOA 11.1.1.1.7) to read the content of a file and the file looks like this

**a|b|c|d|e 

a|b|c|d|e 

a|b|c|d|e 

a|b|c|d|e 

a|b|c|d|e 

 Total no of rows 5**

For reading this , I need to create a xsd.My problem lies in the last line ( 
Total no of rows 5). Guys could you please help me in creating the xsd.My current xsd looks like this..which is not working. Please help

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
        xmlns:tns="http://TargetNamespace.com/File_Outbound_Ref"
        targetNamespace="http://TargetNamespace.com/File_Outbound_Ref"
        elementFormDefault="qualified"
        attributeFormDefault="unqualified"

        nxsd:version="NXSD"
        nxsd:stream="chars"
        nxsd:encoding="US-ASCII"
        nxsd:hasHeader="true"
        nxsd:headerLines="1"
        nxsd:headerLinesTerminatedBy="${eol}"
>
<xsd:element name="Root-Element">
<xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="Data_Details" type="tns:DataReport" nxsd:style="array" />
    <xsd:element name="Trailor_Details" type="tns:Trailor_Record" nxsd:style="array" nxsd:cellSeparatedBy="${eol}" />
     </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
 </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="DataReport">
   <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|" nxsd:quotedBy="&quot;" />
          <xsd:element name="b" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|" nxsd:quotedBy="&quot;" />
          <xsd:element name="c" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|" nxsd:quotedBy="&quot;" />
          <xsd:element name="d" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|" nxsd:quotedBy="&quot;" />
          <xsd:element name="e" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" nxsd:quotedBy="&quot;" />
           </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="Trailor_Record">     <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="Row_Count" type="xsd:string" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}" />    
  </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to edit your question to include the XSD you've come up with so far as a starting point.

Comment: hey. Did you managed to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In Read file action, under "Configure Operation" we have "Remove Trailer" option and enable it and mention the number of row. So in your case you need one last row to remove so mention 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).